# Check if day and hours between another day and hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How can I check if day and hours are between other?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-start="13:00:00" data-end="15:30:00" data-day="monday">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" data-start="13:00:00" data-end="15:30:00" data-day="monday">

<script>
jQuery('[data-start]').on('change',function(e){

 var day= jQuery(this).data('day');
 var start = jQuery(this).data('start');
 var end = jQuery(this).data('end');

 jQuery('[data-day]').each(function(index, element) {
  if(jQuery(element).data('day')==day && (jQuery(element).data('start')>= start && jQuery(element).data('start')<= end) ){
   if(!jQuery(element).prop('disabled')){
    jQuery(element).attr('disabled','disabled');
   }else{
    jQuery(element).removeAttr('disabled');
   }
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

I need disable all others elements what have the same day and between same hours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)